# Is there a way to verify a signed up email?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm using react-native and firebase for my login/signup system.
I want to add the feature that when you signup with a mail and password you receive first a mail that you need to confirm before you can use that account for logging in.

I searched for documentation about it but i couldnt find anything that really fits to the feature.

Answer (score 0):

This have been covered quite a few times before, so I recommend searching for previous answers. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-authentication%5D+verified+before+sign+in

But nowadays I'd probably [use an email link to sign in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth) to Firebase, since that automatically ensures the email account exists.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't work a lot with firebase but iirc there was a way to return a token when signing up and sending it when signing in later.

There is also a way that doesn't involve tokens which is to add a boolean to your DB and send an email with a certain randomly generated id. When the user clicks on the link in the email, you could then send that key to the backend and set the boolean to true.
This approach works as I personally tried it before but it needs effort to make.